# Making single option select/deselect list

Tags: jquery, list, select, toggle

I want to make list of elements where you can select only one option and deselect this option and see original list of elements. And I want to be able to select other element without deselecting currently selected option first. I hope this all makes sense.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4</li>
    <li>Element 5</li>
    <li>Element 6</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#mylist').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $('#mylist li').removeClass('selected');
    $('#mylist li').addClass('not-selected');
    $(this).removeClass('not-selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('#mylist li').removeClass('selected');
        $('#mylist li').removeClass('not-selected');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    display inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0px;
}

ul li.selected {
    background-color: #f535d7;
}

ul li.not-selected {
    background-color: #bbb;
    opacity: .2;
}
```

This is how far I got: http://jsfiddle.net/vaidasb/rMRgF/5/

Answer (score 2):

Change your javascript to this:

```
$('#mylist').on('click', 'li', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $('#mylist li').removeClass('not-selected');        
    }
    else
    {
        $('#mylist li').removeClass('selected').addClass('not-selected');
        $(this).removeClass('not-selected').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As with many things jQuery, you can do it in one line.

```
$('#mylist').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

I'd recommend not using a distinct `not-selected` CSS class. "Not selected" is the default.

This makes both the JavaScript and the CSS code simpler and avoids a "tri-state" situation where the third state is elements that are neither `selected` nor `not-selected`.

If you do not want that the "selected" state can be toggled, use `.addClass()` instead of `.toggleClass()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Aa2NW/

Answer (score 0):

Going off @Tim I think this is what you wanted as far as multiple selects: http://jsfiddle.net/Dcwc5/

Change your javascript like so:

```
$('#mylist').on('click', 'li', function () {

   if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
    {
        //clicked element was previously selected
        //remove his selected status
        $(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('not-selected');
        //check if other's are selected
        if($('#mylist li.selected').length == 0){
            $('#mylist li').removeClass('not-selected');  
        }
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('not-selected')){
        $(this).removeClass('not-selected').addClass('selected');
    }
    else
    {
        //elementw as newly selected
        //all li's remove selected, add not-selected
        $('#mylist li').removeClass('selected').addClass('not-selected');

        //remove not-selected from current element and add selected
        $(this).removeClass('not-selected').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```